# Entity Framework Integration tests DropCreateDatabaseAlways not clearing database between test

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-4.1

I am writing a set of integration tests (Unit tests with MS Test which test that Entity Framework 4.2 is persisting all classes correctly to the database).

When I run all tests one by one they all work fine. When I run them in a group - some of them fail as the wrong number of objects are returned - it would seem that the db is being cleaned down once at the start of the tests and not in between each test - even though I can see a new context being created and then disposed of for each test

Any Ideas?

```
public class EmptyDataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<myContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(myContext db)
    {
        //Do Nothing Create Empty Database
        db.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(db);
    }
}
```

A Cut down version of the unit/integration Tests

```
[TestClass]
public class PersistanceTests
{
    //Creating two instances of our Repository so that we can make sure that we are reading from our database rather than in-memory
    private myContext _db;
    private myContext _dbResults;
    private readonly ISettings _configSettings;

    public PersistanceTests()
    {
        _configSettings = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISettings>();
        _configSettings.ConnectionString = "data source=.;initial catalog=myContext_Test; Integrated Security=SSPI; Pooling=false";

        Database.SetInitializer(new EmptyDataInitializer());
    }

    //This is called a single time after the last test has finished executing
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDownTest()
    {
       _db.Dispose();
        _db = null;
       _dbResults.Dispose();
        _dbResults = null;
    }

    //This is called each time prior to a test being run

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {          
        _db = new myContext(_configSettings);
        _dbResults = new myContext(_configSettings);

        // This forces the database to initialise at this point with the initialization data / Empty DB
        var count = _db.Accounts.Count();
        var resultCount = _dbResults.Accounts.Count();
        if (count != resultCount) throw new InvalidOperationException("We do not have a consistant DB experiance.");
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void OrganisationPersistanceTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var apple = new Organisation { Name = "Apple" };
        _db.Organisations.Add(apple);
        // Act
        _db.SaveChanges();
        var organisationsCount = _dbResults.Organisations.Count();
        var organisationsAppleCount = _dbResults.Organisations.Where(a => a.Id == apple.Id).Count();
        var result = _dbResults.Organisations.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == apple.Id);
        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(organisationsCount == 1, string.Format("Organisations Count Mismatch -  Actual={0}, Expected={1}", organisationsCount, 1));
        Assert.IsTrue(organisationsAppleCount == 1, string.Format("Apple Organisations Count Mismatch -  Actual={0}, Expected={1}", organisationsAppleCount, 1));
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Organisations Result should not be null");
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Name, apple.Name, "Name Mismatch");
    }

    //A Unit test
    [TestMethod]
    public void OrganisationWithNumberOfPeople_PersistanceTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var person = new Person { Firstname = "Bea" };
        var anotherPerson = new Person { Firstname = "Tapiwa" };
        var apple = new Organisation { Name = "Apple" };
        apple.AddPerson(person);
        apple.AddPerson(anotherPerson);
        _db.Organisations.Add(apple);
        // Act
        _db.SaveChanges();
        var organisationsCount = _dbResults.Organisations.Count();
        var organisationsAppleCount = _dbResults.Organisations.Where(a => a.Id == apple.Id).Count();
        var result = _dbResults.Organisations.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == apple.Id);
        var peopleCountInOrganisation = result.People.Count();
        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(organisationsCount == 1, string.Format("Organisations Count Mismatch -  Actual={0}, Expected={1}", organisationsCount, 1));
        Assert.IsTrue(organisationsAppleCount == 1, string.Format("Apple Organisations Count Mismatch -  Actual={0}, Expected={1}", organisationsAppleCount, 1));
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Organisations Result should not be null");
        Assert.AreEqual(result.People.Count, peopleCountInOrganisation, "People count mismatch in organisation Apple - Actual={0}, Expected={1}", peopleCountInOrganisation, 2); 
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Name, apple.Name, "Name Mismatch");
   }
```

}

Stepping through the tests I can see the SetupTest and TearDownTest methods being called but  I it does not seem to clean down the database between tests.

Comment: Okay Dokey it would seem an answer (though seems a bit hackish to me) is to modify the TestCleanup Method so that it explicitly drops and recreates the database after each test

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TearDownTest()
        {
            if (_db.Database.Exists())
            {
                _db.Database.Delete();
                _db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            }            
            _db.Dispose();
            _db = null;
          
           _dbResults.Dispose();
            _dbResults = null;
        }

Comment: Okay even Better answer - add a database.Initialize(force: true);
into the TestInitialize method.

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {          
        _db = new myContext(_configSettings);
        _db.Database.Initialize(force: true);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay even Better answer - add a database.Initialize(force: true);
into the TestInitialize method.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupTest()
{          
    _db = new myContext(_configSettings);
    _db.Database.Initialize(force: true);
    _dbResults = new myContext(_configSettings);

    // This forces the database to initialise at this point with the initialization data / Empty DB
    var count = _db.Accounts.Count();
    var resultCount = _dbResults.Accounts.Count();
    if (count != resultCount) throw new InvalidOperationException("We do not have a consistant DB experiance.");
}
```

Comment: This works with a regular connection (non-MDF), do you have a hint why the same code won't work when the connection string includes the `AttachDBFilename` parameter? After the call to `.Initialize(true)`, EntityFramework does delete the .MDF file within the specified path, yet throws an SQL Exception complaining that the .MDF file cannot be found! Does this have something to do with some recovery flags/options I left on? This looks like a pretty random behaviour to me!

Answer (score 2):

I use a helper for doing this kind of tasks:

```
public abstract class TestingHelper
{
        public static void ClearDatabase()
        {
            DatabaseContext myDbContext = new DatabaseContext();
            myDbContext.Database.Delete();
            myDbContext.Database.Create();
            //FillDatabase(lawyers); //<- OPTIONAL if you want to add rows to any type tables
        }
}
```

And then use it in the SetUp of your test:

```
[SetUp]
public void MyTests_SetUp()
{
      TestingHelper.ClearDatabase();
}
```